# How display two columns in Mvc WebGrid with single object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am new to `MVC` and I want to display name of a user in two columns in a `WebGrid` as display below.

[image]

Currently the web grid display data in below format.

[image]

I am binding my `WebGrid` with `List<string>`, list contains username.

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    List<string> userList = new List<string>();
    userList.Add("User1");
    userList.Add("User2");
    userList.Add("User3");
    userList.Add("User4");
    return View(userList);
}
```

My Cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column(format: (item) => item)));
}
```

Comment: so essentially you want to break your row after every two users. Correct? if you had 6 rows then there will be three rows in all. Correct?

Comment: Any reason you are not showing any header in your table?

Comment: I'm getting a feeling that webGrid is a wrong choice.In your list each string represents one record which in essence is a row. You should rather write simple loop along with table html elements to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Correct I have to break row after every two records.

It is a requirement to not show any headers, just display Users.

It will be a great help if you please suggest me how do I achieve a desire outcome with loop in a table.

Comment: Ohh.. then it is pretty straightforward. Let me add an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output is not the right use-case for a webgrid control. Here is the table generation logic for mvc razor view using simple for loop:

```
@model List<string>
<table >
            @{ 
                for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        @:<tr >
                    }
                    <td style="border:solid;">
                            @Model[i - 1]
                    </td>

                     if (i % 2 == 0)
                     {
                         @:</tr>
                     }
                  }
              }
    </table>
```

I've added a css style `style="border:solid;"` just to show border of all the table cells. You can customize it as per your needs.

This code creates below table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution it really helps me.

Comment: Great! If this solution resolved your problem then you can accept the solution by clicking the green check mark below the voting buttons. This will help the community focus on unanswered questions on this site.